# How do I remove a app using its name with powershell?

Tags: powershell, script, uninstall

I'm trying to write a script that can remove apps using the DisplayName from this piece of code

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

but I don't know if that is possible. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: 1st - DO NOT use `Format-*` cmdlets for anything other than FINAL output to a file or the screen. it destroys the objects, wraps the chopped bits in formatting code, and then sends out stuff that is useless for other things. use `Select-Object` or build a `[PSCustomObject]` instead. ///// 2nd - take a look at `Get-Help *-Package` for some ideas. [*grin*]

Comment: There are already scripts written to do this. What research have you done?

Comment: Suggestions: You have to use the value from the `UninstallString` to uninstall more than likely. Consider piping over to `| Uninstall-Package` maybe getting with `Get-Package $pName | Uninstall-Package` or something like that. Look over `(Get-Package).Name` output and these are what you might be able to pipe over to `Uninstall-Package`... There's also WMI and other ways see here for a few examples for instance: https://superuser.com/questions/1483618/uninstall-an-application-without-user-input/1485620#1485620